# RESTful way to respond when related resource is affected

Tags: rest, http, json-api

Say there is a resource named Draft '/api/drafts/' and another one named Revision '/api/revisions/'. They are related with one-to-one relationship.

To create Revision, you make the request POST on '/api/revisions/' and provide draft id in the argument. JSON API way of doing this means

```
POST /api/revisions/
Content-type: application/json

{
    "data": {
        "type": "revision",
        "links": {
            "draft": { "linkage": { "id": 1, "type": "draft" } }
        }
    }
}
```

This creates Revision resource and it is related to Draft id=1. So the response will be the following:

```
201 Created
Content-type: application/json
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "revision",
        "links": {
            "draft": { "linkage": { "id": 1, "type": "draft" } }
        }
    }
}
```

However, POST /api/revisions/ has a side-effect; it changes an attribute on draft.

e.g.) draft.revision_count: 0 => 1

However, all the client did was making request to create revision and receiving created revision resource as a consequence and has no way of knowing whether draft's data has changed or not.

My question is, is server responsible to let the client know that by creating revision other resources are affected and need to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server should not tell the client in the response to the `POST /api/revisions` that a *draft* has changed.

But the client should not expect that the client state of the draft it knows is still valid. It should make a request

```
GET /api/drafts/1
If-None-Match: "etag-of-this-draft-the-server-returned-last-time"
```

The value of the `If-None-Match` will be the [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) the server returned in a a reponse the client made for this resource earlier. If the server state of the draft has changed, the ETag will not macth and the client will return the *new* state of the draft. If the server state of the draft did not change, the server will respond with a `304`.

If the client does not make sure that the state it knows matches the current server state, conflicts may happen when the client tries to alter the draft by, for example, making a `PUT` on it. If it includes the `If-None-Match` header in a `PUT` request, the server will be able to detect any mismatch between the current server state and the outdated client state. It can respond with the proper HTTP status code.